# JavaScript call function from new window

Tags: javascript, html

I have scoured the internet and found no answers to this on Stack or anywhere for that matter that actually work.

I developed a SPA (PWA).  Within the SPA the user can click a button to open a new page that contains a pricelist.  This is easy enough.  However, from the new pricelist page I want to be able to call a function from the SPA and pass arguments to that function.  The function is a module that is imported to the original SPA.

Essentially, I want the pricelist page to be able to pass the partnumber from the pricelist page to the shopping cart in the SPA.

Is this even possible?  If so, can you share example or link?

Comment: Not really into pwa but would https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener?retiredLocale=de help?

Comment: You would usually use a query string to pass arguments between windows precisely because windows are isolated from each other, other options are using local or session storage, or even cookies if you don't want the user to see what the params contain

Comment: If the user is logged in through both pages, and you have some mechanism to poll the backend, or notify the frontend from the backend, you can pass the message through the backend API.

Comment: Though i have never used the technique i believe you can also attach an event handle to the window load event via the return of the `window.Open()`

Comment: @David I have tried the window opener.  But, when I call window.opener.ReturnSelectedItem(), I receive the following error... Uncaught TypeError: window.opener.ReturnSelectedItem is not a function.  So, I try to import ReturnSelectedItem as a module but receive and error in vs code that ReturnSelectedItem is declared but value never read.

Comment: @Mike I am leveraging local and session storage, but missing the concept of how to execute a function on the main application from the new pricelist.html window.

Comment: I am wondering if leveraging Broadcast Channel API may be a way to trigger the function in the main application.  I think I will look at that next if no one here has any other ideas.  I think I could pass the string values to the main application and when the message is received then trigger the function.  I'll give it a go...

Comment: you put a flag in the store, if the flag is set you run the function, if not you don't. you can likewise use the store to pas the results between the pages. as the storage is set at the domain level all sub pages can access it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code to handle the communications between the main application and the pricelist page.  It works flawlessly. I had to do a bit of testing to figure it all out.  I am using the BROADCAST CHANNEL API and the SESSIONID.

```js
 // PWA MAIN APPLICATION (index.js)
 const BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01 = new BroadcastChannel(sessionStorage.getItem('SESSIONID'))
 BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.onmessage = (event) => {
     if (event.data.partnumber) {
         ReturnSelectedItem(event.data.partnumber, event.data.model)
         BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage({
             partnumber: event.data.partnumber,
             model: event.data.model
         })
     }
     if (event.data === 'RE-OPEN-CHANNEL') {
         //// RE-OPENS CHANNEL
         BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage(`${'CHANNEL_OPENED'}`)
     }
     if (event.data === 'beforeunload') {
         //// CHANNEL WILL RE-OPEN IF PAGE WAS ONLY REFRESHED AND NOT CLOSED
         setTimeout(() => {
             BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage(`${'CHANNEL_OPENED'}`)
         }, 1000)
     }
 }
 //// LET PRICELIST PAGE "KNOW" IT CAN NO LONGER ADD TO MAIN APP CART
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
     BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage(`${'beforeunload'}`)
 })

 //PRICELIST.js
 const BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01 = new BroadcastChannel(
   sessionStorage.getItem('SESSIONID')
 )
 BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.onmessage = (event) => {
   if (event.data === 'CHANNEL_OPENED') {
     sessionStorage.setItem('BROADCAST_CHANNEL', 'OPENED')
   }
   if (event.data === 'beforeunload') {
     sessionStorage.setItem('BROADCAST_CHANNEL', 'CLOSED')
     //// CHANNEL WILL RE-OPEN IF PAGE WAS ONLY REFRESHED AND NOT CLOSED
     setTimeout(() => {
       BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage(`${'RE-OPEN-CHANNEL'}`)
     }, 1000)
   }
 }
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
   BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage(`${'beforeunload'}`)
 })

 //PRICELIST.js Event Listener to pass in the partnumber/model to the main application
   if (event.target.matches('.quick-add-btn')) {
     if (!event.target.classList.contains('added')) {
       const PART_NUMBER =
         event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].innerText
       const MODEL = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].innerText
       if (sessionStorage.getItem('BROADCAST_CHANNEL') === 'OPENED') {
         BROADCAST_CHANNEL_01.postMessage({
           partnumber: PART_NUMBER,
           model: MODEL
         })
         event.target.innerHTML = '&#10003' //html check mark
         event.target.classList.remove('quick-add-btn')
       }
       if (
         sessionStorage.getItem('BROADCAST_CHANNEL') === 'CLOSED' ||
         !sessionStorage.getItem('BROADCAST_CHANNEL')
       ) {
         CallModal(
           'To use this feature...\r\nOpen the pricelist from the main application...\r\nUse the "Pricelist" button',
           'alert'
         )
       }
     }
     return
   }
```